# Combine :global and * in vim

Tags: vim

In vim I can use `:global/foo` to find lines matching foo. In normal mode I can also use `*` to find the next word under cursor.

Is there any (standard) way to do a `:global` with the word under the cursor? If it is not, what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press `<C-R><C-W>` to insert the word under cursor when editing command line (any command, not just `:global`).

See `:help c_CTRL-R`.

Comment: Very useful! I have modified the map using C-R C-W to preserve the contents of the " register. Thank you!

Comment: @mzcarlos I think you should unaccept my answer and accept this one instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
:map gg* yaw:global/<C-R>"<Enter>
```

Let me explain step by step.

```
:map gg*
```

I decided to use the name `gg*` for the mapping to "extend" the command [`g*`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#gstar). The name is actually bad as it stomps the command [`gg`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#gg). You can use any name you want.

```
yaw
```

Copy the word under cursor into the `"` buffer.

```
:global/
```

Start entering the command in the command line .

```
<C-R>"
```

Paste the buffer `"` into the command line.

```
<Enter>
```

Execute the command.

Comment: Thank you! It works. I didn't know it was possible to use <C-R> in the command line.

Comment: The whole yank/put business is wasteful and `:map` should be `:nnoremap`: `:nnoremap <key> :g/<C-r><C-w><CR>`.